# Activity after splash screen

Tags: java, android, android-activity, splash-screen

Once my splash screen display for 1000ms I receive an error stating "The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." It seems an activity that is supposed to start after the splash screen is not working. before the splash screen, everything worked fine. Logcat
shows the following error " E/AndroidRuntime(5480): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxxx.home/com.xxxxx.home.xxxxx}: java.lang.NullPointerException. I beleive the issue is with my Splash Class but cannot pin point where. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

public class Splash extends Activity{

```
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent openxxxxx = new Intent("com.xxxxx.home.XXXXX");
            startActivity(openxxxxx);

        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}
```

}

Comment: have you register your all activity class in manifeast file?

Comment: Yes... My splash activity registered in the manifest and set to MAIN and LAUNCHER. My Second Activity was changed to DEFAULT and is name was set to the same as the one in "intent"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the complete code you can use this,

```
package com.fsp.slideview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Window;

public class ImageSplashActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * The thread to process splash screen events
     */
    private Thread mSplashThread;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        final ImageSplashActivity sPlashScreen = this;

        mSplashThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        wait(2000);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }

                finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(sPlashScreen, SlideMainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

        mSplashThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            synchronized (mSplashThread) {
                mSplashThread.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow this is epic. Great code. Worked a treat. Thanks @Aerrow

Comment: Im guessing the SlideMainActivity is is a animated slide into view?

Comment: Sorry I am coming at this time, but does anyone know how to run an application after a splashscreen for desktop applications in java???

Comment: @Presh_K7: Sorry, here we discussed mobile screen. May this one can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134549/how-to-make-a-splash-screen-for-gui else google it :)

Comment: @Presh_K7: great...:)