# Run one class and then another

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, splash-screen

I have just made a splash screen class and it all works perfect. I also have anther class which is my game class. Now I just want to know how do I make it so when the user runs the game class in the main function it will run that splash screen class first and then run the game class?

Just to explain if you did not understand as my english is not to good:
I have two classes. One is called `Splash` and anther is called `game` . Now the user will run that game class by running the main method. Now what I want to happen when the main method is run I want the splash class first to run so it shows the splash screen and then for the game class to run straight afterwards. I have both classes working but not sure how to get around this problem.

Comment: In your last question you were given the link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Create a Splash Screen` which does this. So follow the example from the tutorial.

Comment: i have done this but i made into anther class

Comment: So you just invoke the other class. Basiaclly the SplashScreen is just like a modal dialog. You invoke some code and wait for it to  finish. When it finishes the code will continue to execute. So from your JFrame you decide when you want to invoke the SplashScreen. Do you invoke it before you build all the components for the frame. Or do you invoke it after all the components are built but before you make the frame visible. We don't know how you structured your classes so we can't give you a detailed answer.

Comment: See also [How to make a splash screen for GUI?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16134549/418556)

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `interface` that could be passed to the splash screen (for example) that would execute the prescribed method once the splash screen has completed.

Comment: How is your splach screen set up?