# A Starting menu for a tic tac toe game

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am new to java, and trying to create a simple game. The game itself is complete and working, however, I am having trouble creating a title screen. All I want is a title screen that is 600 x 600 which opens up before the actual game, and it has a button that says start. I'm not quite sure how to go by this, can I get some help.

My code for the game is bellow

```
package tictactoemain;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * TicTacToe Assignment
 * @author Ekin
 *
 */
public class TicTacToe 

{
    // Creating a (600, 600) window that can stop the game when he window is closed
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame ticTacToe = new TicTacToeFrame();
        ticTacToe.setTitle("Ekin's Tic-Tac-Toe Game!");
        ticTacToe.setSize(600, 600);
        ticTacToe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ticTacToe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ticTacToe.setVisible(true);
    }


}// end of TicTacToe
package tictactoemain;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
/**
* JFrame to hold TicTacToe board.
*/
public class TicTacToeFrame extends JFrame
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// Indicate whose turn it is
   private char whoseTurn = 'X';
   private boolean gameOver = false;

   // Create cell grid using an Array
   private Cell[][] cells = new Cell[3][3];

   // Create a status label
   JLabel jlblStatus = new JLabel("X's turn to play");

   /**
    * No-argument Constructor
    * @return 
    */
   public TicTacToeFrame()
   {
       // Panel to hold cells
       JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 0, 0));
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
               panel.add(cells[i][j] = new Cell());

       panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 1));
       jlblStatus.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.yellow, 1));

       add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       add(jlblStatus, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }
   // Determine if it's a tie
   /**
    * Determine if game board is full.
    * @return True, if game board is full. Otherwise, false.
    */
    public boolean isFull()
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
               if (cells[i][j].getToken() == ' ')
                   return false;
       return true;
    }
    // Check to see if a player (Token) has won
   /**
    * Determines if a given token has won.
    * @param token Token to test for winning
    * @return True, if the token has won. Otherwise, false.
    */
   public boolean isWon(char token)
   {
       // check rows
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           if ((cells[i][0].getToken() == token)
                   && (cells[i][1].getToken() == token)
                   && (cells[i][2].getToken() == token))
           {
               return true;
           }

       // check columns
       for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
           if ((cells[0][j].getToken() == token)
               && (cells[1][j].getToken() == token)
               && (cells[2][j].getToken() == token))
           {
               return true;
           }
       // check diagonals
       if ((cells[0][0].getToken() == token)
               && (cells[1][1].getToken() == token)
               && (cells[2][2].getToken() == token))
           {
               return true;
           }

       if ((cells[0][2].getToken() == token)
               && (cells[1][1].getToken() == token)
               && (cells[2][0].getToken() == token))
           {
               return true;
           }

       return false;
   }

    /**
    * Defines a cell in a TicTacToe game board.
    */
    public class Cell extends JPanel
    {
       /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // token of this cell
       private char token = ' ';

       /**
        * Constructor
        */
       public Cell()
       {
           setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
           addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
       }

       /**
        * Gets the token of the cell.
        * @return The token value of the cell.
        */
       public char getToken()
       {
           return token;
       }

       /**
        * Sets the token of the cell.
        * @param c Character to use as token value.
        */
       public void setToken(char c)
       {
           token = c;
           repaint();
       }

       @Override
       protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
       {
           super.paintComponent(g);

           if (token == 'X')
           {
               g.drawLine(10, 10, getWidth() - 10, getHeight() - 10);
               g.drawLine(getWidth() - 10, 10, 10, getHeight() - 10);
           }

           else if (token == 'O')
           {
               g.drawOval(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);
           }
       }
       // MouseListener to listen for a click to place a token
       private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
       {
           @Override
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
           {
               if (gameOver)
                   return;

               // if the cell is empty and the game is not over
               if (token == ' ' && whoseTurn != ' ')
                   setToken(whoseTurn);

               // Check game status
               if (isWon(whoseTurn))
               {
                   jlblStatus.setText(whoseTurn + " won! Game over!");
                   whoseTurn = ' ';
                   gameOver = true;
               }
               else if (isFull())
               {
                   jlblStatus.setText("Tie game! Game over!");
                   whoseTurn = ' ';
                   gameOver = true;
               }
               else
               {
                   whoseTurn = (whoseTurn == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';
                   jlblStatus.setText(whoseTurn + "'s turn to play.");
               }
           }
       } // End class MyMouseListener
    } 
} // End class TicTacToeFrame
```

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134549/how-to-make-a-splash-screen-for-gui or the Java tutorial on [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) ... O'Reilly has a [simple example](http://examples.oreilly.com/jswing2/code/ch08/SplashScreen.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I am copying code from my painting app with a starting screen, do not copy paste this code. Write some yourself! :)

What I do is add an ActionListener to the button, and tell the button to close the start screen and open the main screen when clicked. Here is the code example (from my paint app):

```
private class StartListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        startFrame.setVisible(false); //close start window
        paintApp.go(); //the go function contains code for opening the 
                       //main window
                       //the paintApp is an object that contains both
                       //JFrames, starting and main 
    }
}
```