# Change the splashscreen imagem by the date

Tags: java, desktop-application, splash-screen

I'm trying to create a function that changes the splashscreen image when a specific date is near, like:

```
30/nov/2017 - Default splashscreen

01/des/2017 ~ 31/des/2017 - Christmas theme splashscreen

01/jan/2018 - Default splashscreen
```

I've created the splash screen putting `SplashScreen-Image: splashdemo/splash.png` inside the `manifest.mf` AND `-splash:src/splashdemo/splash.png` in `Properties > Run > VM Options`.

My main is basically this:

```
package splashdemo;

public class Splashdemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

The splash works fine as expected, but now I want to change the image somehow. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach at the moment relies on you re-releasing your application each time the date range changes.

I'd suggest you package the three images in the jar, and then dynamically determine the splash screen name based on date, and then call the SplashScreen class directly with the correct image.

See these links

- [How to make a splash screen for GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134549/how-to-make-a-splash-screen-for-gui)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html